# How do I convert this linux command to python string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a linux command :

> jq -r '."meta-version" |= "abc"' temp.json > folder1/folder2/abc.json

Which runs fine on the terminal, but I want to convert it into a python string and execute using a python script. I am getting error, how do I convert it into a python string
For Example:

> var = "jq -r '."meta-version" |= "abc"' temp.json > folder1/folder2/abc.json"

Comment: You can use triple quotes `""" .... """`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var = "jq -r '.\"meta-version\" |= \"abc\"' temp.json > folder1/folder2/abc.json"
```